# Changing or Turning off _FillValues

Tags: python, missing-data, netcdf

I want to either turn off the filling or change the _FillValue to None/NaN in the NetCDF file.  How do you do this?  I have tried looking it up and nobody talks about it.  When I output a variable such as longitude, this  is what I get:

**float32 lons(lons)
    units: degree_east
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (720,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used**

I have also tried masking, but it still gives me the information above.

Here is some code I have:

```
  lati = numpy.arange(-89.75,90.25,0.5)
  long = numpy.arange(-179.75,180.25,0.5)

  row = 360
  column = 720

  dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(r'Y://Projects//ToriW//NC Files//April2.nc', 'w', format = 'NETCDF4_CLASSIC')

  dataset.misisngValue = None
  dataset.filling = "off"
  dataset.createDimension('lats',row)
  dataset.createDimension('lons',column)

  lats = dataset.createVariable('lats', 'f4',('lats'))
  lats.units = 'degree_north'

  lons = dataset.createVariable('lons','f4',('lons'))
  lons.units = 'degree_east'

  print (lons)

  lats[:] = lati
  lons[:] = long     
  Pre = dataset.createVariable ('Pre',numpy.float64, ('lats','lons'))

  Pre[:,:] = total

  dataset.close()
```

}

Comment: Does your typo `misisngValue` make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[_Fill_Value](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset.set_fill_off) is the proper name for the attribute you want.

```
dateset.set_fill_off()
```

should work.

```
dataset.setncattr("_Fill_Value", None)
```

might work. I'm not sure, but will work to change the _Fill_Value.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I think the proper name is _FillName, but it is set for each variable in the dataset. I tried setting it like this: dataset.variables[varname]._FillValue = 99 but this was the error message I got: "_FillValue attribute must be set when variable is created (using fill_value keyword to createVariable)"