# Change _FillValue in netCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

Is there a python netCDF4 command/example to change the global metadata _FillValue in a netCDF file? I have tried replacing all -ve values in a netCDF file, but till the time the _FillValue attribute is set, that does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe python netCDF4 has a specific function for this, but [NCO's ncatted](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncatted-netCDF-Attribute-Editor) is an ideal tool for this task.

From the docs:

To change the missing value from the IEEE NaN value to a normal IEEE number, like 1.0e36:

```
ncatted -a _FillValue,,m,f,1.0e36 in.nc
```

Comment: It can be done in python netCDF4,  _FillValue is a global attribute. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38685109/1211981

Comment: Adding -t may be useful, since this adds the attribute only to double-precision variables (see documentation)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use cdo to set the missing entries to another value, for example 999.0

```
cdo setmisstoc,999.0 in.nc out.nc
```

However, from the description of your problem, it seems that you don't actually need to change the value for _Fillvalue but instead you want to set negative values to missing. You can achieve this by using the cdo function "set range to miss"

```
cdo setrtomiss,-1e8,0 in.nc out.nc
```

the first argument is a big negative number that is smaller than the smallest value in your dataset.   I'm assuming in the above answer that the field in question does already have a value set, otherwise you would need to add it with e.g.

```
cdo setattribute,field@_FillValue=-1.e32 infile outfile
```

In general it seems that defining a "global" _FillValue can cause issues (e.g. see https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/issues/458) and anyway if you have a combination of integer and float fields then defining a default float fill can not be applied to all fields. I'm personally of the opinion that it is best practise to define a fill value for each field separately and if possible use the defaults for each data type.

cdo commands can be called directly from python using the cdo package.

Comment: Is there a way to set an attribute in place with CDO?

Comment: yes, cdo setattribute,field@units=mm infile outfile for example, but that is a different question, why not post it on SO and I'll answer it there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A _FillValue is specific for a variable. With Python NetCDF4 library, I understand that it can only be specified when the variable is created. The _FillValue can be changed though with CDO. This is how I changed a _FillValue myself:

```
cdo -setattribute,Band1@_FillValue=-1.0 infile.nc outfile.nc
```